# Subscription Filter Pattern for API Gateway Execution Logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

Are there any Subscription Filter Patterns to pass API Gateway Execution Logs into Elasticsearch? I really am unable to find any good answer out there as to do this. Originally I was using Access logs, but then I needed to log response header values, as well as values from the body at times, to implement audit logging functionality which I am hoping to be able to do for our requirements at the API Gateway level, so that I don't have to add a new dependency to every project we have. There doesn't seem to be any good **Log Format *** for API Gateway. For example if I select the CLF format, that isn't going to play nice.

[image]